# Terraform Google provider: Unable to allocate IP addresss range for Private Service access

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

In terraform, I am unable to allocate IP address for [GCP Private service access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access).

Relevant Terraform code:

```
resource "google_compute_address" "allocate_psa_range" {
  name          = "psa-cidr"
  region        = var.region
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc.self_link
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address       = "10.225.1.0"
  prefix_length = 24
}
```

**Error:**

> Error: Error creating Address: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/<gcp_project_name>/regions/asia-south1/subnetworks/default' was not found, notFound

It seems terraform is looking for subnet information. I did not provide any, so I guess it is looking for a default subnet.

**Debugging:**

Referring the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_address#subnetwork), The subnet needs to be provided only when *"used with INTERNAL type with GCE_ENDPOINT/DNS_RESOLVER purposes."*
In my case, I am using `VPC_PEERING` under `purpose`.  Also, it is not realistic to provide an IP Range for private access connect from a given subnet.

Besides, I am able to allocate the private access IP range via `gcloud cli` without any inputs on subnet:

```
gcloud compute addresses create psa-cidr \
--global \
--purpose=VPC_PEERING \
--addresses=10.225.1.0 \
--prefix-length=24 \
--description="IP address range for PSA" \
--network=<gcp_network_name>
```

I looked at this reported [issue from 2018](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/2541) which suggests to provide subnet info. However per current terraform documentation referred above, this is not needed besides, it does not seem practical as well.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using wrong terraform resource. The correct resource for this purpose is [google_compute_global_address](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_global_address)